# How to find a files with multiple instances of substring in Pycharm search

Tags: regex, pycharm

I need to search through the whole Project files where `"sub_string"` appears twice (might appear on different lines).

I tried

```
(sub_string){2}
```

but it seems that it'd work only in case this text appears twice in sequence: `"...sub_stringsub_string..."`

So how to search for files where substring appears twice and not in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this if you only specifically want 2 instances is with the following:

```
.*sub_string.+sub_string.*
```

This doesn't scale nicely manually if you want more than 2 occurrences, but you can always use a loop to generate the regex string and go from there.

An example can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/2PU9yv/2).

Comment: It works for cases when 2 substrings appear on the same line. Is there a way to do the same for case when substrings appear on different lines? Is there a specific modifier for the same?

Comment: Yes that can be done. Do you want them to appear on different lines completely, or just when there is text between the two occurrences?

Comment: Both occurrences might appear on same line (one by one divided by comma or with another text between them) or on two different lines

Comment: Answer has been updated @JaSON you just need to use `+` instead of `*` in the middle, that way one or more characters must be matched

Comment: With `+` instead of `-` I see no changes. But I guess I got correct result with `.*sub_string.*[\n]*.*sub_string.*`. Thank you for help